# How to assign variable "name" attribute to <input> element in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jsp

Below is the image in which I am trying to make user interface. Here, I am creating this using loop in JSP.

Now, I want to give the name of every input element a unique value, so that they can be distinguished. That's why I want to give them variable name attribute which I can set and value in JSP using that name.

I want to know if JavaScript can be able to do this or not. If not, then which language I can choose?

[image]

---

> Code I am using in JSP are following. Here, in resultSet variable which is type of ResultSet, I am getting the data stored in database and showing it on screen.

```
 <% while (resultSet.next()) { %> <%= resultSet.getString("ExamID")%></td> 
    <input type="text" name="marks" placeholder="Marks" size="10" />
 <% } %> <input type="submit" name="enter" value="submit" />
```

Comment: You should easily be able to assign a dynamic name to the element when it is being generated in the jsp, without having to use jquery or javascript to do this.  Please provide your jsp logic that is generating the markup.

Comment: Code I am using in JSP are following. Here, in resultSet variable which is type of ResultSet, I am getting the data stored in database and showing it on screen.             

<%  while (resultSet.next()) { %>               
    <%= resultSet.getString("ExamID")%></td>           
    <input type="text" name="marks" placeholder="Marks" size="10" />        
<% } %>          
<input type="submit" name="enter" value="submit" />

Answer (score 0):

this is the angularjs equivalent
http://jsfiddle.net/f6mma2jz/

html:

```
<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='ControllerA'>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Exam Id</td>
    <td>Obtained Mark</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="result in resultSet">
    <td>{{result.id}}</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="enter" placeholder="Marks" ng-model="result.mark"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="enter" value="submit" />
   Model::{{resultSet}}
</form>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('ControllerA', function($scope) {

   $scope.resultSet = [{id:1401001},{id:1401002},{id:1401003},{id:1401004}]
});
```